# How to use a Map to call an action on an object

Tags: java

I want to call a specific setter in a generic piece of code. Of course, I can resort to a case statement, but its going to grow large, so I prefer a Map.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
public class Tester {

private static final Map<String, Setter<Target, ?>> MY_SETTERS = new HashMap<>();
static {
    MY_SETTERS.put("SOURCE1",  ( Target t, Source1 s ) -> t.setSource1( s ) );
    MY_SETTERS.put("SOURCE2",  ( Target t, Source2 s ) -> t.setSource2( s ) );
}

@FunctionalInterface
private interface Setter<T, S> {

    void set( T target, S source );
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    Target t = new Target();
    MY_SETTERS.get( "SOURCE1" ).set( t, new Source1() );
}}
```

However, this gives me a "incompatible types: Source1 cannot be converted to CAP#1
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?"

I understand why its failing. However, is there an elegant way to do this without resorting to a case statement?

Comment: Is it out of the question to just write explicit getters for every `Setter<T, S>`? So you would just be stuck with `MY_SETTERS.getSource1Setter().set(t, new Source1());`. Of course, this does have the downside that you need to know exactly which setter you're dealing with each time.

Comment: @Obicere .. The problem is that my real casus is a large JAXB generated choice class with rather a lot of entries. I want to handle them generic because the remainder of the processing steps is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of that wildcard type in the map, you have to draw a line somewhere. This is slightly ugly, but it is what I sometimes do:

Define a generic helper method which will cast the `Setter` to your requested type:

```
public static <T, S> Setter<T, S> getSetter(String id) {
    return (Setter<T, S>) MY_SETTERS.get(id);
}
```

Retrieve and invoke the setter like this:

```
getSetter("SOURCE1").set(t, new Source1());
```

Java will infer type arguments from your passed parameters and the invocation itself will look fine. You will get complaints from the compiler due to that unchecked cast though.

Obviously you have to be absolutely sure what you request is what you expect to get as otherwise you will get a `ClassCastException`. E.g. doing the following will produce said exception, as you retrieve setter for `Source1` but invoke it with `Source2`:

```
getSetter("SOURCE1").set(t, new Source2());
```

Comment: This is the perfect way to [pollute the heap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html).

Comment: Can you please elaborate why? It's not modifying the map.

Comment: I removed my downvote because you have shown the danger of `ClassCastException` with a clear example. I meant just what you've shown.

Comment: @Justas,  I was playing with the idea to make my own class based on a map to establish the relation. I would then use the source class as key. Something like this:    private static class MyMap<T, S> {

        private final Map<Class<S>, Setter<T, S>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

        private void put( Class<S> s, Setter<T, S> setter ) {
            myMap.put( s, setter );
        }

        private void set( S source, T target ) {
            myMap.get( source.getClass() ).set( target, source );
        }

    }. .problem: source.getClass() gives me Class<?> iso Class<Source>

Comment: @sjaak, you will still run into the same problem as long as you have an unbounded type `?`. With your `MyMap` implementation you just moved the problem elsewhere. You want to have a type-safe setter but at the same time the setters are for different types - because of that, you will end up casting something somewhere. So it's either that the `Setter` works with a common supertype (e.g. `Source`) or you do a cast like in my answer, when fetching the setter.

Comment: @Justas you are right.. I went with your solution. Somehow it feels like a shortcoming in Java Generics.. But I'm sure it has a reason :).